# PLSQL Dynamic Row Count in results

Tags: plsql

In PL SQL is there a way to produce the Order Count per customer as follows...  Thanks for your help.

```
Cust     Order#    Order Count
ABC1     011       1 
ABC1     052       2
ABC1     199       3
BBA1     150       1
BBA1     158       2
```

Thanks
Gavin

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code of your stored procedure that you want to change. Especially the part that does the retrieval

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, a little bit of analytics might do the job. Here's an example:

```
SQL> with test (cust, order#) as
  2    (select 'ABC1', '011' from dual union all
  3     select 'ABC1', '052' from dual union all
  4     select 'ABC1', '199' from dual union all
  5     select 'BBA1', '150' from dual union all
  6     select 'BBA1', '158' from dual
  7    )
  8  select cust, order#,
  9    row_number() over (partition by cust order by order#) order_count
 10  from test;

CUST ORD ORDER_COUNT
---- --- -----------
ABC1 011           1
ABC1 052           2
ABC1 199           3
BBA1 150           1
BBA1 158           2

SQL>
```

Comment: This was perfect thank you, and thank you to all those who helped me, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want a GROUP BY such as

```
select cust, SUM(order_count)
from MyTable
group by cust;
```

which should yield

```
cust   SUM
ABC1   6
BBA1   3
```